# How to create a template language

Tags: c#-4.0, template-engine

I am not sure how to explain this and not sure if thats the right title. You may edit this post and title to make it more clear.

Here is what I need to do. We have a CMS and would like to simplify creating pages. Instead of using raw C# to create page templates we want to use a simpler language. For example.

**Old way:**

```
<span>User name: <%= Model.UserName %></span>
```

**New way:**

```
<span>User name: {Username}</span>
```

As you can see the new way is much simpler. But I didn't want to stop there. i would like to include conditionals, loops variables and other very simple scripting concepts to be parsed by C#. Is there a known method to do this or any ready made code I can use to make this possible.

**Edit:**

The reason I need something like this is to make the page highly dynamic. This template language will not only be used for presenting a webpage. it will be used to fetch data from the database, load information from other webpages, construct dynamic data, create calculated data on the fly. This means I can insert the template code in a post then it will run the custom template (scripting code) on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/), which uses Microsoft's new Razor template language.

It's even lighter than your example.

Comment: Actually, I also needed this template code to run on the backend as well. It will not only be used in creating web pages.

Comment: @Luke101: What would that mean?

Comment: I would need the razor engine to have capability to fetch info from the database, create variables, loop through data, and be able to be ran on the fly. Is this possible with only razor?

Comment: @Luke101: Razor supports arbitrary C# or VB.Net code.  You may be interested in my [in-depth series of blog posts](http://blog.slaks.net/search/label/dissecting-razor).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Mustache project, it is very mature and work in both ends (back and front-end):

http://mustache.github.com/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET MVC?
If it's MVC then there are already many different ViewEngines that let you create pages in different ways.

Look here:

http://sparkviewengine.com/, http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/